# Loop through JSON & Compare time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What i'm trying to accomplish is to loop through this JSON, and compare the "start_time" and "end_time" to ensure the times don't overlap. I'm having trouble implementing this.

I found this: [validate two times](http://hibbard.eu/how-to-validate-that-two-time-ranges-dont-overlap-in-javascript/) but none of it makes any sense nor is it using JSON but it's the closest i've found. Could I use jQuery to do this?

```
{
    "Line_1":{
        "artist":"Audien",
        "day":"1",
        "start_time":"13:00",
        "end_time":"14:00",
        "stage":"main"
    },
    "Line_2":{
        "artist":"Slushii",
        "day":"1",
        "start_time":"13:30",
        "end_time":"14:30",
        "stage":"eclipse"
    },
    "Line_3":{
        "artist":"DJ Snake",
        "day":"1",
        "start_time":"15:00",
        "end_time":"16:00",
        "stage":"main"
    },
    "Line_4":{
        "artist":"Marshmello",
        "day":"2",
        "start_time":"14:15",
        "end_time":"15:15",
        "stage":"horizon"
    }
}
```

Expected output:

> Audien & Slushii Conflict!
>
> DJ Snake Does not Conflict with anyone!
>
> Marshmello Does not Conflict with anyone!

*Notice Days 1 & 2

Comment: *Note: There can be as many "Line_" objects since the form is built to be dynamic.

Comment: Absolutely! I actually looked into it but wasn't sure if I was able to use it since it required a date and I won't be using dates, just comparing times based "day:1", "day:2" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather verbose prototype for your learning purposes. It uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and [twix.js](http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/).

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/5v7yksk3/4/

**HTML for prototype code:**

```
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

**JS for prototye code**

```
var data = {
        "Line_1":{
            "artist":"Audien",
            "day":"1",
            "start_time":"13:00",
            "end_time":"14:00",
            "stage":"main"
        },
        "Line_2":{
            "artist":"Slushii",
            "day":"1",
            "start_time":"13:30",
            "end_time":"14:30",
            "stage":"eclipse"
        },
        "Line_3":{
            "artist":"DJ Snake",
            "day":"1",
            "start_time":"15:00",
            "end_time":"16:00",
            "stage":"main"
        },
        "Line_4":{
            "artist":"Marshmello",
            "day":"2",
            "start_time":"14:15",
            "end_time":"15:15",
            "stage":"horizon"
        }
    },
    tmp_day = '2000-01-01',
    outer_key,
    outer,
    inner_key,
    inner,
    tmp_range,
    checked = {},
    conflict_found = {},
    conflicts = [],
    i;

for (outer_key in data) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, outer_key)) {
        outer = data[outer_key];

        tmp_range = moment(tmp_day + 'T' + outer.start_time).twix(tmp_day + 'T' + outer.end_time);

        checked[outer_key] = true;

        for (inner_key in data) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, inner_key) &&
                outer_key !== inner_key &&
                !checked[inner_key]
            ) {
                inner = data[inner_key];

                if (outer.day === inner.day &&
                    (
                        tmp_range.contains(tmp_day + 'T' + inner.start_time) ||
                        tmp_range.contains(tmp_day + 'T' + inner.end_time)
                    )
                ) {
                    conflict_found[outer_key] = true;
                    conflict_found[inner_key] = true;

                    conflicts.push([
                        outer_key,
                        inner_key
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output:
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '';

for (i = 0; i < conflicts.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<li><strong>' + data[conflicts[i][0]].artist + '</strong> conflicts with <strong>' + data[conflicts[i][1]].artist + '</strong></li>';
}

for (outer_key in data) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, outer_key) &&
        !conflict_found[outer_key]
    ) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<li><strong>' + data[outer_key].artist + '</strong> does not conflict with anyone</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, a bit complicated but I think I could break it down. Is there any way to alter it so if someone's "end_time" = someone else's "start_time" it doesn't conflict?

IE: 
"Line_4":{
         "artist":"Marshmello",
         "day":"2",
         "start_time":"14:15",
         "end_time":"15:15",
         "stage":"horizon"
     },
      "Line_5":{
         "artist":"Swag",
         "day":"2",
         "start_time":"13:15",
         "end_time":"14:15",
         "stage":"horizon"
     }

Does not conflict?

Comment: Yes, it is intentionally avoiding some of the newer array/collection stuff in order to avoid shims and such in the fiddle. I didn't want to distract from the basic logic. I am sure twix.js could handle your allowance for start time matching end time with something like its `overlaps`, `engulfs`, or something else in place of the `contains` I used. Click through the link to the twix.js page and take a look at what it offers.

Comment: It could even be as simple as another condition of the `if` that starts at line 57 that would check for identical end time of one and start of the other.

Comment: So I added this statement: inner.end_time !== inner.start_time on 57 but not sure how to compare the inner.end_time to the inner.start_time of another or vise versa. I really do appreciate your help and i'm learning a ton from your prototype code!

Comment: So I've been playing around, working out an OOP variety of this, and seeing if I can handle the issue with start/end being at the same time. I came up with something that does NOT count those as a conflict by default, but would if you passed an option telling it to do so. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/5v7yksk3/6/

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you very very much. This is way more than expected! I really appreciate it and it looks so well written. Currently going through all comment lines learning all I can from this.

Comment: No problem, I was itching to write some JS. :) I hope it sends you in the direction of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
var json = {
  "Line_1":{
    "artist":"Audien",
    "day":"1",
    "start_time":"13:00",
    "end_time":"14:00",
    "stage":"main"

  },
  "Line_2":{
    "artist":"Slushii",
    "day":"1","start_time":"13:30",
    "end_time":"14:30",
    "stage":"eclipse"

  },
  "Line_3":{
    "artist":"DJ Snake",
    "day":"1",
    "start_time":"15:00",
    "end_time":"16:00",
    "stage":"main"

  },
  "Line_4":{
    "artist":"Marshmello",
    "day":"2",
    "start_time":"17:15",
    "end_time":"15:15",
    "stage":"horizon"

  }
};

function timeToDate(timeStr) {
    var whateverDate = '01/01/1980  '; 
    return Date.parse(whateverDate + timeStr);
}

for (item in json) {
    var st = json[item].start_time;
    var et = json[item].end_time;
    var datesCorrect = (timeToDate(st) < timeToDate(et)) ? 'true' : 'false';
    console.log(item + ' dates correct: ' + datesCorrect);
};
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dhf89twr/1/